# Can anyone explain this python statement using for loop with dictionaries?

Tags: python

```
s=";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in {"server":"mpilgrim", "database":"master", "uid":"sa", "pwd":"secret" }.items()])
print(s)
```

.
Current output is:

```
server=mpilgrim;database=master;uid=sa;pwd=secret
```

.
thanks.

Comment: Just a side note, if you don't understand a big one liner like this try to break it down into his component in multiple lines. That usually help a loy in parsing it!

Answer (score 5):

This is a list comprehension, it iterates over each element in the dictionary, where `k` and `v` will be the key and values respectively.

For each element the iteration will reproduce a string like `"%s=%s" % (k, v)` which means a key and a value will be conjoined by an = sign, producing `database=master` for example.

The list comprehension produces a list of these elements, and than each element is joined together by a ; sign using the join function.

Answer (score 0):

The code for an intuitive understanding is:

```py
result = ''
for k, v in {"server":"mpilgrim", "database":"master", "uid":"sa", "pwd":"secret" }.items():
    string_ = k + "=" + v
    result = result+string_
print(result)
```

```
server=mpilgrimdatabase=masteruid=sapwd=secret
```

1. your code, each of `string_` variables is in list. (by using list comprehension)
2. and then all `string_` variables are attached with the `=`.  (by using `.join`)

```py
print(",".join("abc"))  # use string  
print(",".join(["a","b","c"])) # use list
```

```
a,b,c
a,b,c
```